# Why is my PHP output scrambled when I provide an input for the printed javascript call?

Tags: php, ajax

I'm generating HTML code in a PHP file, and then returning the result to an AJAX function to include it in an already loaded web-page.

My code is:

```
$schoolName=$row->name;
echo "<td><b onclick=\"selectSchool(\"$schoolName\")\">$schoolName</b></td><td>{$row->stateName}</tr>";
```

The expected result would be:

```
<td><b onclick="selectSchool("Foo")">Foo</b></td>
```

But what I get is an ugly melange:

```
<td><b angeles)")"="" (los="" university="" lincoln="" abraham="" onclick="selectSchool(">Abraham Lincoln University (Los Angeles)</b></td>
```

If I were simply getting an un-desireable result I wouldn't be so concerned, but for some reason the output is becoming totally scrambled and I have no clue why.  I cannot figure out where things like 'los=""' are coming from!

If I don't use a variable inside the selectSchool() function call, then I get the expected output, but that's not useful at this point, I need to be able to pass the appropriate value into the function for it to work!

Requested var_dump:

```
string 'Abraham Lincoln University (Los Angeles)' (length=40)

object(stdClass)[3]
  public 'name' => string 'Abraham Lincoln University (Los Angeles)' (length=40)
  public 'stateName' => string 'California' (length=10)
```

Comment: Try `var_dump($row->name, $schoolName);`

Comment: `<td><b onclick="selectSchool("Foo")">Foo</b></td>` is not valid.  The `"` inside the `onclick` should be escaped or `'`.  `<td><b onclick="selectSchool(\"Foo\")">Foo</b></td>` or ``<td><b onclick="selectSchool('Foo')">Foo</b></td>``

Comment: The "my code is" as it stands right now is a syntax error. What does the real code look like?

Comment: D'oh, how did I miss that (the quotes inside quotes thing)?

Comment: Adjusted the code provided above.  The actual code is a bit confusing because it includes a '">' section that closes off a prior bit of a HTML code.  I didn't think that was important, and I accidentally lopped off a bit of code I shouldn't have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you just use single quotes when passing parameter to `selectSchool()` like this?

`<td><b onclick=\"selectSchool('$schoolName')\">$schoolName</b></td><td>{$row->stateName}</tr>";`

That way you'll get the following result

`<td><b onclick="selectSchool('Foo')">Foo</b></td>`

This won't break the HTML

Comment: Fixes the problem!  I don't understand WHY it fixes the problem, but fixes it it does!

Comment: @RonLugge Because you need to escape the double quotes you were using or replace them with single quotes that way it won't break your HTML code.

Comment: @RonLugge: Because `<td><b onclick="selectSchool("Foo")">Foo</b></td>` is not valid HTML/JavaScript.  You can't have the double quotes in double quotes (without being escaped).

Comment: Because according to your code, you escape the both double quote for PHP, `onclick=\"selectSchool(\"` but you forget to escape the second double quote `...School(\"` for JavaScript. Its should by like this `...School=(\\\"$school...`

Comment: OK, I get it now.  I'm going to guess that the scrambled mess that comes out is the result of Javascript becoming confused during the AJAX stage.

Answer (score 2):

I guess it's because you have quotes in your text (") you should pass your `$schoolName`variable throw [addslashes](http://ru.php.net/addslashes) function.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your suggestion.  I don't need to use add slashes because once it's in a string, a quote character is a quote character.  If I were passing it into a database or otherwise evaluating it that might be necessary, but that's not the case.  Remember, escaping exists only to differentiate for your code the difference between the quote character in a string, and the quote character used to delineate the string.  Once it's in a string, it's just a hex value corresponding to the quote symbol in a character table.